# Is there a way I make a defined variable reset every time I use it?

Tags: ruby

This is the code

```
x = 10
y = 11
def z(q,x,y)
   q = q - (x + y)
end
q = 30
z(q,x,y)
puts "#{q}"     
q = 40 
z(q,x,y)
puts "#{q}"
```

Is there a way that z(q,x,y) would reset every time I use it?

Comment: explain what you want to happen please.

Comment: i want z(q, x, y) to work when used so the first puts is 9 and the second puts is 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = 10
y = 11

def z(q,x,y)
   q = q - (x + y)
end

q = 30
z1 = z(q,x,y)
puts "#{z1}"     

q = 40 
z2 = z(q,x,y)
puts "#{z2}"
```

prints (using puts):

```
9
19
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't modify params.  In function z, q is a parameter that's been set but I think you are also wanting it to be an outside variable and mutate its state.

Here's what you want to do but *please do not do this*.

```
x = 10
y = 11

def z(q,x,y)
   $q = q - (x + y)
end

$q = 30
z($q,x,y)
puts "#{$q}"

$q = 40
z($q,x,y)
puts "#{$q}"

# Prints:
# 9
# 19
```

This is probably bad code.  Why?  Globals are bad.  Mutating state like this when we are blessed to have a mathematical function so pure like this is a war crime and might cause rioting.  We have a math function that doesn't need to change state.  We don't really want z to be responsible for:

- computing a new value
- setting a local variable for use later

The second part is the damning part.  Z knows about its outside world when it doesn't need to.

Look at this which is similar to the other answer already here:

```
x = 10
y = 11

def z(q, x, y)
  q - (x + y)
end

q = z(30, x, y)
puts q

q = z(40, x, y)
puts q
```

If you are starting out with Ruby or programming in general, read a lot of code and watch screencasts of people working live.  It's the fastest route to leveling up a little bit.  It's ok if it doesn't happen right away, the next time you try will be easier (years later maybe).